# Qt creator: stacked widget pop up

Tags: qt, popup, qstackedwidget

I´m kind of new in Qt Creator and  have a few stacked widgets on my project so my question is: can the stacked widgets be pop up? and how can I do it?
Also I have a Qt 5.5.1 with MinGW 32bit on pc.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can handle the mouse hover events and do anything there (**show your popup widget**).
Override  QWidget::enterEvent(QEvent * event), QWidget::leaveEvent(QEvent * event). These events are called when mouse enters or leaves the widget.

Something like that...

```
void YourParentWidget::enterEvent(QEvent * event)
{
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

    QPoint pos = mapToGlobal(QPoint(x, y));
    mYourPopUpWidget.move(pos);
    mYourPopUpWidget.show();
}

void YourParentWidget::leaveEvent(QEvent * event)
{
    mYourPopUpWidget.hide();
}
```